# How to determine most Important/Informative features using Linear Support Vector Machines (SVM) classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, text-classification

I am new to python and working on a text classification problem. I am interested in the visualization of the most important features of each class through a linear SVM classifier model. I want to determine which features are contributing towards the classification decision as Class-1 or Class-2 by classification model. This is my code.

```
df = pd.read_csv('projectdatacor.csv')
df = df[pd.notnull(df['types'])]
my_types = ['Requirement','Non-Requirement']

#converting to lower case
df['description'] = df.description.map(lambda x: x.lower()) 

#Removing the punctuation
df['description'] = df.description.str.replace('[^\w\s]', '')  


#splitting the word into tokens
df['description'] = df['description'].apply(nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize) 


## This converts the list of words into space-separated strings
df['description'] = df['description'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x))
count_vect = CountVectorizer()  
counts = count_vect.fit_transform(df['description']) 


#tf-idf
transformer = TfidfTransformer().fit(counts)
counts = transformer.transform(counts)  

#splitting the data and training the model
#naives-bayes
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(counts, df['types'], test_size=0.3, random_state=39)

#svc classification
from sklearn import svm
svclassifier = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001, C=100., kernel = 'linear')

svclassifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = svclassifier.predict(X_test) 

#evalutaing the model
print(classification_report(y_test,y_pred))
print(confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred))  
print('accuracy %s' % accuracy_score(y_pred, y_test))
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred,target_names=my_types))
```

I have read all related questions available on this platform but I found the following useful code which I added in my code.

```
import numpy as np 
def show_most_informative_features(vectorizer, clf, n=20): 
    feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names() 
    coefs_with_fns = sorted(zip(clf.coef_[0], feature_names)) 
    top = zip(coefs_with_fns[:n], coefs_with_fns[:-(n + 1):-1]) 
    for (coef_1, fn_1), (coef_2, fn_2) in top: 
        print ("\t%.4f\t%-15s\t\t%.4f\t%-15s")  % (coef_1, fn_1, coef_2, fn_2) 
show_most_informative_features(count_vect, svclassifier, 20)
```

This code works for naive Bayes and logistic regression and it gives the most important features but for SVM it gives me the error.

I am getting this error.

```
  File "C:\Users\fhassan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 704, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\fhassan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "U:/FAHAD UL HASSAN/Python Code/happycsv.py", line 209, in <module>
    show_most_informative_features(count_vect, svclassifier, 20)

  File "U:/FAHAD UL HASSAN/Python Code/happycsv.py", line 208, in show_most_informative_features
    print ("\t%.4f\t%-15s\t\t%.4f\t%-15s" % (coef_1, fn_1, coef_2, fn_2))

TypeError: must be real number, not csr_matrix
```

Any help shall be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you:

```
from sklearn import svm
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
corpus = [
    'This is the first document.',
    'This document is the second document.',
    'And this is the third one.',
    'Is this the first document?']

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)

x=X.toarray()
y=[0,0,0,1]

model=svm.SVC(kernel='linear')

a=model.fit(x,y)
model.score(x,y)

feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names() 
coefs_with_fns = sorted(zip(model.coef_[0], feature_names)) 
df=pd.DataFrame(coefs_with_fns)
df.columns='coefficient','word'
df.sort_values(by='coefficient')
```

You will get:

[image: Output]

Comment: Thanks, @Rubens_Zimbres for the comment. I am trying this in my code and it is not giving me the required results. May you please help me which part of my code should be changed to get the required results. I am new to python so please ignore if I am doing any big mistake. I modified your code as follows to get the required results but it didn't help me.
May i please know where I am actually doing mistake.

Comment: I have modified the code as follows.
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

        X_train=counts.toarray()
        y_train=[0,1]

        model=svm.SVC(kernel='linear')

        a=model.fit(X_train, y_train)
        model.score(X_train, y_train)

        feature_names = count_vect.get_feature_names() 
        coefs_with_fns = sorted(zip(model.coef_[0], feature_names))
        coefs_with_fns = sorted(zip(model.coef_[1], feature_names)) 
        df=pd.DataFrame(coefs_with_fns)
        df.columns='coefficient','word'
        df.sort_values(by='coefficient')

Comment: This is the error I am getting.


      File "C:\Users\fhassan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 235, in check_consistent_length
    " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])

    ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1720, 2]